# transmit touch from uiview to uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview

Here is the structure of my xib

uiview
--uiview
--uiwebview

I have made changes so that the uiview is transparent. What is the way to send the touch events which are delivered to touchesBegan of uiview to the touchesBegan of uiwebview ?

Answer (score 1):

Please go the following link and read the section under "Basics of Touch-Event Handling", i hope after you will get the idea how events trigged down to other/sub views.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html